# What are the steps to find the oblique asymptote of this function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The oblique asymptote of $\frac{x^2}{2x - 5}$ is $\frac{x}{2}+\frac{5}{4}$. What steps do I need to take in order to get from the original function to the oblique asymptote?

Comment: You can show that $\frac{x^2}{2x-5}-\frac{x}{2}-\frac{5}{4}$ goes to $0$ as $x$ goes $+\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply top and bottom by $2x + 5$ to complete the square. Then we have:

$$\frac{x^2(2x+5)}{(2x)^2 - 5^2} = \frac{2x^3+5x^2}{4x^2 - 25}$$

and dividing by $x^2$, we get:

$$\frac{2x+5}{4-25/x^2}$$

As $x$ tends to infinity, $25/x^2$ tends to $0$, so we are left with $\frac{2x+5}{4} = \frac{x}{2} + \frac{5}{4}$.

Comment: Hmm, what prevents me to divide by $x$ right away and get $\dfrac{x}{2-\frac 5x}$ and we are left with $\dfrac x2$ only ?

Comment: @zwim Once you do that, you can only conclude that $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ of the function diverges, and you will be left with nothing to tell you about the function's oblique asymptote.

Comment: @zwim The highest-order term of $\frac{x^2}{2x-5}$ is an $x$ term, then a constant term, then a $1/x$ term and so on when you expand it out, for example using polynomial long division. You need both the $x$ term and the constant term to find the oblique asymptote.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you, but there is a more useful form. We could divide by $x$ in $x^2 - 2x + 1 = 0$, but this won't help us solve the equation.

Answer (score 1):

You can do polynomial division to get:
$$\frac{x^2}{2x-5} = \frac{x}{2}+\frac{5}{4}+\frac{25}{8x-20}$$ Now the last part will “disappear” as $x \to \infty$ and so you will be left with the oblique asymptote.

Answer (score 0):

A general way to find an asymptote (at $x \to \infty$) is to use the derivative (you can consider the asymptote as the tangent of the curve at $\infty$):

$\begin{align*}
  f(x)
    &= \frac{x^2}{2 x - 5} \\
  f'(x)
    &= \frac{2 x^2  - 10}{(2 x - 5)^2} \\
  \lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x)
    &= \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}$

This gives the slope $m$. To get the intercept, just compute;

$\begin{align*}
   \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) - m x
     &= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^2}{2 x - 5} - \frac{x}{2} \\
     &= \frac{5}{4}
\end{align*}$

Thus the asymptote is:

$\begin{align*}
  \frac{x}{2} + \frac{5}{4}
\end{align*}$

Comment: This question is tagged with `algebra-precalculus` so I do not think an approach using derivatives is appropriate.